# Typescript - Interfaces or classes for domain objects and DTO in Clean architecture?

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I don't have much experience with Typescript nor implementing architecture patterns with it, but we are working in a project that we want to use Clean Architecture but I have the doubt of using `class` or `interface` for declaring DTO and Domain objects.

My assumptions are that for `Domain Objects` it is a good idea to have it as `class` since they could have business logic within. Example:

```
export class Person {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  title: string;

  constructor() {}
  
  someBusinessLogic() {
    // Implement some business logic
  }
```

But for `DTO`, since they should not have any logic, I am working with `interface`:

```
export interface PersonEntityDto {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  title: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  createdAt: string;
}
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

yes, your assumption is correct.
but using an interface for domain objects is not denied by an "official" rule, there is some case where Interface is useful.
My advice if you use an interface you should respect the Liskov principle.